# Setting default html of div to be modified by keyup() event

Tags: jquery, keyup

I have a `textarea` whose value I want to duplicate into another `div` as a preview.  It works fine, except that `keyup` seems to automatically clear the `div` to which it will be writing.  Is there any way to prevent this?  It's a usability concern not to have the default text appear in my output `div`.

```
$('.preview-wrap').html('<textarea maxlength="118" class="tweet" placeholder="My default"></textarea>');

$(".tweet").keyup(function (event) {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $('.tweet-preview').text(value);

 }).keyup();
```

See this fiddle for full example-- the "Output" area should include the "My default" text as indicated.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2f27Z/)**

Thanks!

Comment: do you want "My default" text in preview div and remove when typing text in textarea ?

Comment: Exactly.  It should say "my default" until the user types into the Input text area, then be replaced with that text.

Comment: Write this  
`var value = ($(this).val())?$(this).val():$(this).attr('placeholder');`  
instead of this  
`var value = $(this).val();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the update code

```
$(".tweet").keyup(function (event) {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $('.tweet-preview').text(value);
    //console.log($('.tweet-preview').text() == '')
    if( $('.tweet-preview').text() === '' ){
        $('.tweet-preview').text("My Default")
    }
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2f27Z/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

we can do this by `JQuery` - `CSS` trick, change your code with this.

---

HTML:

```
<div class="tweet-preview" placeholder="My Placeholder String" 
style="border:1px solid #666; min-height: 30px;" >My default</div>
```

---

JQuery:

```
$('.tweet-preview').attr("placeholder", $('.tweet').attr('placeholder'));
```

---

CSS:

```
[class=tweet-preview]:empty:not(:focus):before{
    content:attr(placeholder);
    color: #b3b3b3;
}
```

---

So we are creating FAKE PLACEHOLDER for your div.

Full Working [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/NikhilButani/cBLC2/)